# SQL query to find Date, TranscationAmount_US,TransactionAmount_UK

Tags: sql, aggregate, case-when

We have 2 tables:

```
Transaction (AccountId,Date,TransactionAmount)
Master(Aid,Country)
```

We need to find `Date`, `TotalTAmt_US`, `Total_TAmt_UK`

My solution:

```
Select
  Date,
  CASE WHEN Country in ('US') THEN SUM(TransAmt) ELSE '0'END AS TotalTAmt_US,
  CASE WHEN Country in ('UK') THEN SUM(TransAmt) ELSE '0'END AS TotalTAmt_UK
FROM
(
SELECT
  T.Date As Date,
  M.Country As Country,
  SUM(T.TransAmt) As TransAmt,
FROM
  Transaction T JOIN Master M On T.Aid = M.Aid
WHERE Country in ('US','UK')
group by Date,Country
) As T1
group by Date;
```

Is this right?
Can we use Country in `CASE WHEN` without pulling it as I do not want to pull it and then group by it.

Advice please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare in GROUP BY section all columns that you use in select statement.
So just put your cases to the grouping.

```
Select
  Date,
  CASE WHEN Country in ('US') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END AS TotalTAmt_US,
  CASE WHEN Country in ('UK') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END AS TotalTAmt_UK
FROM
(
  SELECT
    T.Date As Date,
    M.Country As Country,
    SUM(T.TransAmt) As TransAmt,
  FROM
    Transaction T JOIN Master M On T.Aid = M.Aid
  WHERE Country in ('US','UK')
  GROUP BY Date,Country
) As T1
GROUP BY Date, CASE WHEN Country in ('US') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END AS   
         TotalTAmt_US, CASE WHEN Country in ('UK') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END  
         AS TotalTAmt_UK
```

Additionaly, remove the SUM() function in your case conditions. If you put them to the GROUP BY you can get error:

```
ORA-00934: Group function is not allowed here.
```

And, in the end, remove the ticks in zeros in ELSE conditions. You can get another error about incosistens data types.

Comment: Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to do a conditional aggregation getting the sum for all US based transaction for a day and the sum of all the UK based transactions for the same day. Then you had to move the `CASE` into the `sum()`, adding the amount only if the country is the one you look for, otherwise zero.

Also your subquery isn't necessary.

```
SELECT t.date,
       sum(CASE m.country
             WHEN 'US' THEN
               t.transamt
             ELSE
               0
           END) totaltamt_us,
       sum(CASE m.country
             WHEN 'UK' THEN
               t.transamt
             ELSE
               0
           END) totaltamt_uk
       FROM transaction t
            INNER JOIN master m
                       ON m.aid = t.accountid
       WHERE m.county IN ('US',
                          'UK')
       GROUP BY t.date;
```

If you don't insist on having the different sums in different columns, but would also accept rows, it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT m.country,
       t.date,
       sum(t.transamt) totaltamt
       FROM transaction t
            INNER JOIN master m
                       ON m.aid = t.accountid
       WHERE m.county IN ('US',
                          'UK')
       GROUP BY m.country,
                t.date;
```

Comment: Nope.. I need it in different columns. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Country in ('US') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTAmt_US,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Country in ('UK') THEN TransAmt ELSE 0 END) AS TotalTAmt_UK
FROM Transaction T JOIN
     Master M
     On T.Aid = M.Aid
WHERE Country in ('US', 'UK')
GROUP BY Date;
```

Notes:

- You do not need two levels of aggregation.
- Numbers should not be enclosed in single quotes, so `0`, not `'0'`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yeah. '0' it is typo. About WHERE condition if we already have the filtered  countries in CASE WHEN we do not need WHERE condition, right?

Comment: @Drishti . . . No, you do not.  But you had the filtering.  The code might be more efficient with the filter if you have lots of rows with other countries.